# How to implement chunk processing using custom ItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch 2.1.9.RELEASE

I need to configure a job-step which reads the data from Mysql DB, process it and write back to Mysql. I want to do it in chunks.

I considered using `JdbcCursorItemReader` but the SQL is a complex one. I need to fetch data from three other tables to create the actual SQL to use in the reader.

But if I use a `customItemReader` with `JdbcTemplate`/`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, how can i make sure the step processes the data in chunk? I am not using JPA/DAOs.

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you declare a SQL view in MySQL?

Comment: unfortunately I can't change or update the schema for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring-batch data are normally processed as chunk; the easy way is to declare a `commit-interval` in step definition; see [Configuring a step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html).

Another way to define a custom chunk policy is to implements your own [`CompletionPolicy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/CompletionPolicy.html).

To answer your question use the [Driving Query Based ItemReaders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) to read from main table and build complex object (reading from other tables), define a `commit-interval` and use the standard read/process/write step pattern.

I hope I was clear, English is not my language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to do this using JdbcCursorItemReader with a custom PreparedStatementSetter. I built the SQL in  @PostConstruct and set the PreparedStatement parameters in setValues(...) method.